# iTextShaprt make new line feed for each block in Header

Tags: asp.net-core, itext

I am trying to use the iTextSharp Library to read PDF files. The example code from [devTo](https://dev.to/eliotjones/reading-a-pdf-in-c-on-net-core-43ef) is as following:

```
var reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\..\sample.pdf"));

for (var pageNum = 1; pageNum <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNum++)
{
// Get the page content and tokenize it.
var contentBytes = reader.GetPageContent(pageNum);
var tokenizer = new PrTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(contentBytes))

var stringsList = new List<string>();
while (tokenizer.NextToken())
{
    if (tokenizer.TokenType == PrTokeniser.TK_STRING)
    {
        // Extract string tokens.
        stringsList.Add(tokenizer.StringValue);
    }
}

// Print the set of string tokens, one on each line.
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", stringsList));
}
reader.Close();
```

But this code just makes every found test in a new line feed. I need to get every block found in the PDF as a sentence or sentences. Any other block should be in new Line feed.

In the header of the PDFs I am testing, there is three columns (receiver of bill at left, information of organization at the middle and information of the sender at the right side). After that begins the body of the PDF.

How can I catch that in code? Does anyone have meet this problem before? I really appreciate any help!

Comment: A PDF document contains something you could call objects. An object can contain any number of symbols (letters, ciphers, ...) - zero or more. It depends on the creator of the file in how many pieces one line of text is cut in the PDF 'source code'. If you want to see the inner part of a pdf, you can use https://github.com/itext/i7j-rups, but just going through the list of your resulting strings gives you an idea of how the PDF is built.

Comment: For proper text extraction with iText you should use code from its content parsing API. Beware, though, it is only present in iText 5.x and 7.x.